# How to populate a Generic List from a JSON string using C#.NET?

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am trying to populate a List in C# but the values are not appearing in the array - though it does not throw an error until I try and set a variable with an array index (because it is out of range of course).

This is the exact return string `strJSON` I am seeing while debugging.

```
strJSON "{\"id\":34379899,\"name\":\"Revelation22\",\"profileIconId\":547,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1387913628000}"
```

Why is the List (array) not populating?

This is the code for KeyValue.cs (which to be honest I do not know yet why it needs another class)

```
namespace LoLSummoner
{
    public class KeyValue
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string name {get; set;}
        public int profileIconId {get; set;}
        public int summonerLevel {get; set;}
        public int revisionDate {get; set;}
    }
}
```

And this is the code from Summoner.svc.cs

```
namespace LoLSummoner
{
    public class Summoner : ISummoner
    {

        public int GetSummonerID(string SummonerName)
        {
            int summonerId = 0;

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string strJSON = client.DownloadString("http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.2/summoner/by-name/" + SummonerName + "?api_key=xxxx");

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            KeyValue[] arrJSON = js.Deserialize<List<KeyValue>>(strJSON).ToArray();

            summonerId = Convert.ToInt32(arrJSON.GetValue(0));

            return summonerId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Your `RevisionDate` property has to be `long`, because `1387913628000`, and that's the value your trying to deserialize, exceeds `int` range.
2. Your JSON contains information about only one `KeyValue` object, not an array of there, so you have to deserialize it as `KeyValue`, no `KeyValue[]`:

   ```
   KeyValue item = js.Deserialize<KeyValue>(strJSON);
   ```
3. Having `KeyValue` instance you can use standard property syntax to return `ID`:

   ```
   return item.id;
   ```

I find this code working:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = @"{""id"":34379899,""name"":""Revelation22"",""profileIconId"":547,""summonerLevel"":30,""revisionDate"":1387913628000}";

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

     var item = js.Deserialize<KeyValue>(input);

     var summonerId = item.id;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your JSON contains a single object, not an array.
Therefore, you can only deserialize it as `KeyValue`.

Comment: Should I be parsing this another way then? Can't I just split the string on :

Comment: @JoJo: You don't have a list, so don't pretend that you do.  `js.Deserialize<KeyValue>(strJSON)`

Comment: sorry getting `No parameterless constructor defined for type` how can I get an answer to my question? Should I ask again? What do I need to study in order to know what is going wrong?

Comment: Defined for which type? What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

As already noted, the revisionDate will cause a runtime binding exception if it is not typed as a **long**.

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```

In addition to that, you may wish to attempt a simple detection in order to deserialize this as either an object or an array of objects (if in the future the name is no longer unique).

```
public int GetSummonerID(string SummonerName)
{
    int summonerId = 0;

    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string strJSON = client.DownloadString("http://prod.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.2/summoner/by-name/" + SummonerName + "?api_key=xxxx");

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    if(strJSON[0] == '[')
    {
        return js.Deserialize<KeyValue[]>(strJSON)[0].id;
    }
    else
    {
        return js.Deserialize<KeyValue>(strJSON).id;
    }
    return summonerId;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I do not know yet why it needs another class

You don't need that class. It think the simplest way would be to deserialize your json directly to `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
var strJSON = "{\"id\":34379899,\"name\":\"Revelation22\",\"profileIconId\":547,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1387913628000}";

var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer()
           .Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(strJSON);

Console.WriteLine(dict["name"]);
Console.WriteLine(ToDateTime((long)dict["revisionDate"]));
```

---

```
DateTime ToDateTime(long l)
{
    return  new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(l);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing to note is that your JSON string contains only a single `KeyValue`, not a list of them. Another problem is that the revision date is too large to fit in a 32 bit int, so consider using a long instead.

Here's some example code that reads your sample string and prints out some of the values.

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var strJSON = "{\"id\":34379899,\"name\":\"Revelation22\",\"profileIconId\":547,\"summonerLevel\":30,\"revisionDate\":1387913628000}";
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    var keyValue = serializer.Deserialize<KeyValue>(strJSON);
    var id = keyValue.id;
    var name = keyValue.name;
    var level = keyValue.summonerLevel;

    Console.WriteLine("Summoner name:{0}, Id:{1}, Level:{2}", name, id, level);
    Console.Read();
}
```